# Troubles by understanding arity of terms in A Course in Universal Algebra.

Tags: soft-question, definition, universal-algebra

In [A Course in Universal Algebra](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/univ-algebra.pdf) in definition 10.1 **terms** are introduced.

What puzzles me is the statement about arity:

> "A term $p$ is $n$-ary if the number of variables appearing explicitly in $p$ is $\leq n$."

Does that mean that the arity of a term $p$ is at most limited but not defined, and can take several values?

If e.g. $p$ is a variable then can every integer $\geq1$ be put forward as arity of $p$?

This seems to be confirmed in the definition 10.2 (also troubling me) where for term $p(x_1,\dots,x_n):=x_i\in X$ a mapping $p^{\mathbf A}:A^n\to A$ is prescribed by $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto a_i$.

I really do not understand this definition.

If I just start with term $x$ wich is a variable  then according to def. 10.2 $x^{\mathbf A}$ must be some function $A^n\to A$. But if so, then what is $n$ (can it take several values?) and how is the function prescribed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've got it (ugly as it seems). The point is that a term *on its own* isn't a "complete" object, and so it doesn't have a unique arity.

---

Certainly there's no problem talking about the arity of a *map* from $A^n$ to $A$ (namely, just $n$). The point is that a single term can have multiple different interpretations as functions, and these yield different arities. You point this out yourself.

Specifically, for any term $p$ and any set $V$ of variables such that every variable occurring in $p$ is in $V$, we can view $p$ as a map $p_V: A^V\rightarrow A$. Note that the translation $(p,V)\mapsto p_V$ is completely straightforward; this is why one will (sadly) often conflate $p$ and $p_V$ when $V$ is clear from context.

- Note that there's no requirement here that $V$ be finite!

In light of this, it isn't too weird to allow a term to have multiple arities - the point being that in some sense a term on its own is *incomplete* (for spiritual similarity, one might argue that the graph of a function is incomplete since it doesn't tell you the codomain).

Comment: Thank you Noah. Light starts shining, but (as always) I need time to digest.

Comment: You are saying that every (finite I guess) set $V$ induces together with $p$ a map $p_V:A^{|V|}\to A$. I understand, but shouldn't we say that for every *linear ordered* finite set $V$? If for instance $p$ is variable $x$ then it must be clear which projection (there are $|V|$ in total) is denoted by $p_V$, right? I asked a similar question to @Eran.

Comment: @drhab Yes, what you're saying is correct for finitary operations. However, a more general definition would be to interpret to domain $A^V$ as the collection of all functions from $V$ to $A$. Think of these elements of the domain as "$V$-tuples."  Then, I would call $f : A^V \to A$ a $V$-ary operation on $A$.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo Ah, so actually everything will be okay immediately if we replace $|V|$ by $V$ here so that $p_V:A^V\to A$. Then the order I was asking for is present. Next to that it has the advantage that it eventually can be expanded to infinite $V$. Do I understand you correct?

Comment: @drhab Yes, exactly! And see the comment I'm about to post after Erin's answer.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo Thank you very much!

Comment: @drhab You're right, I should have written "$V$" rather than "$\vert V\vert$" - fixed!

Comment: Light is really shining brightly now, as it should at Christmas time :-). Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I wouldn't even define arity for a term; I would only define it for a term operation. Let me try to be more precise:

Let $X$ be a set of symbols, called *variables*, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of *operation symbols* such that each operation symbol $f$ has an *arity*, $\mathrm{ar}(f)$, that is a non-negative integer. The set $\mathrm{T}(X)$ of all *terms* in $X$ is defined recursively:

1. every variable $x$ or operation symbol $c$ with $\mathrm{ar}(c)=0$ is in $\mathrm{T}(X)$,
2. if $t_1,\dots,t_k$ are terms and $f$ is an operation symbol with $\mathrm{ar}(f)=n$, then $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ is in $\mathrm{T}(X)$.

Now, let $X_k=\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ and let $\mathbf{A}$ be an algebra of type $\mathcal{F}$. To every term $t$ in $\mathrm{T}(X_k)$ we can define a $k$-ary operation $t^A$ on $A$ as follows:

1. if $t=x_i$ or $t=c$ with $\mathrm{ar}(c)=0$, then $t^A:A^k\to A$ is defined by $t^A(a_1,\dots,a_k)=a_i$ or $t^A(a_1,\dots,a_k)=c^A$, respectively.
2. if $t=f(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, then $t^A(a_1,\dots,a_k)=f^A(t_1^A(a_1,\dots,a_k),\dots,t_n^A(a_1,\dots,a_k))$.

The important thing to notice is that terms are just formal strings of symbols whereas when we assign meaning to a term in a specific algebra that is how we arrive at term operation. Based on this, I feel no reason to define arity for a term and the arity of a term operation is just the arity of the operation. I will conclude with an example:

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{+,-,0\}$. Then $t=(x_1+(-x_2))+x_3$ is in $\mathrm{T}(X_3)$, but it is also in $\mathrm{T}(X_k)$ for any $k\geq 3$. So, given an algebra $\mathbf{A}$ of type $\mathcal{F}$, we can define the term operation $t^A:A^3\to A$ by $t(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1+(-a_2))+a_3$ or we could define it $t^A:A^k\to A$ for any $k\geq 3$ by $t(a_1,\dots,a_k)=(a_1+(-a_2))+a_3$. This first term operation has arity equal to 3 and the second one has arity equal to $k$, but there is no reason to define arity for $t$.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a good look at this (and also the answer of Noah).

Comment: The first 2. in your answer starts with "if $t_1,\dots,t_k$.." but I suspect the $k$ must be $n$ here. Correct? Secondly after the second 1. in your answer you define $t^A$ as the $i$-th projection if $t=x_i$. So the index $i$ is determining. Doesn't that ask for a tuple $<x_1,\dots,x_n>$ instead of a set $X_k=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, or otherwise for a set $X_k$ having $k$ elements that is accompanied by a linear order? Maybe that was done implicitly already by introducing indices for the elements of $X_k$.

Comment: @drhab When trying to write programs to handle general operations and terms, (Andrej Bauer showed me) it's easier to handle arities in a more general way.  For finitary operations or terms, input arguments are finite tuples, like $a = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$, but a tuple is really a function $a : \{1,2,\dots, n\} \to A$ (or replace $A$ with $T$ if you want input arguments to be terms).  More generally, if $\rho : F \to \alpha$ is a function from operation symbols to the "arity" type $\alpha$, then operations have type $f : A^{\rho f} \to A$.  The arity type $\alpha$ can be fairly general.

Comment: If you know Coq, and you want to see how this is actually implemented (in dependent type theory), look [here](https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/3cc438ab38646516e5e9278fdb22022c), or if you know Lean, look [here](https://github.com/UniversalAlgebra/lean-ualib/blob/master/src/basic.lean).

Comment: Everything is clear to me now, and this answer was very very useful. So was the one of Noah (and also the comments of @WilliamDeMeo). Actually I regret that I can only accept one answer. Thanks a lot!